# Change color bars according to hex

Tags: r, ggplot2

For this plot

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(stock = c("google", "google", "amazon", "amazon", "amazon", "yahoo", "yahoo", "yahoo"), status = c("open", "close", "open", "buy", "close", "open", "buy", "close"), category = c("daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily"), price = c(330379.36, 52324.62, 545240.22, 192574.83, 46721.34, 477658.62, 146724.44, 42721.78))
```

and plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(fill=stock, y=price, x= status)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
    ggtitle("Daily") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0, hjust=0)) +
    geom_text(aes(label=price), position = position_dodge(width= 1), vjust=1) + coord_flip()
```

How can somenone change the colors of stock using this specific hex:

```
google #ff53aa
```

amazon #492ecb
yahoo #5041ae

Comment: Rather a lot to this question. So, you're looking to have the bars ordered by price (highest to lowest) within each `df$status`?   How do you want the coloring of the bars to work?  In other words, if they are applied to `df$stock`, which one is bronze, silver, and gold?

Comment: @chemdork123 I updated the question with the hex colors for every stock and made it more simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]try it this way

```
ggplot(df,8 aes(fill=stock, y=reorder(price, status), x= status)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  ggtitle("Daily") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0, hjust=0)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=price), position = position_dodge(width= 1), vjust=0.5) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#492ecb",  "#5041ae", "#ff53aa")) +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: @thank you. The name in the plot of reorder(price, status) could it be price only?

Comment: was happy to help. I did not understand the question. if you need to change the name of the axis, then you can add  `... + labs(y = "price")`