# Show number instead of e in axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

For this plot

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(stock = c("google", "google", "amazon", "amazon", "amazon", "yahoo", "yahoo", "yahoo"), status = c("open", "close", "open", "buy", "close", "open", "buy", "close"), category = c("daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily"), price = c(330379.36, 52324.62, 545240.22, 192574.83, 46721.34, 477658.62, 146724.44, 42721.78))
```

and plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(fill=stock, y=price, x= status)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
    ggtitle("Daily") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0, hjust=0)) +
    geom_text(aes(label=price), position = position_dodge(width= 1), vjust=1) + coord_flip()
```

How can the axis with the number show a number and not 4e32 this option?

Comment: `options(scipen = 999)`

Comment: @RonakShah it worked, thanks

Comment: @RonakShah any idea for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62997128/change-color-bars-short-them-and-show-the-number-in-axis